# How to install .deb with dpkg non-interactively?

Tags: dpkg

I'm trying to install a .deb file... for example:

```
example.deb
```

But the program is already installed in an older version on the Debian minimal server.

So doing `dpkg -i example.deb` is creating a dialog, if i want to keep the configs...
is there any way to do this non-interactive?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pipe `yes` into it:

```
yes | dpkg -i package.deb
```

[`man yes`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!
Thanks :)

Comment: With `yes 4 | dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb` doesn't works :(

Obtain:  `wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb`

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be looking for

```
dpkg --force-confold -i package.deb
```

to specify that `dpkg` should prefer the existing, old configuration files in the case when there is a conflict.

More broadly, the proper solution depends on how desperate you are to avoid interactive prompts, and which prompts precisely you want to avoid.

`dpkg` has a number of options to select a particular behavior for various types of situations. Refer to its [man page;](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg) scroll to the section on `--force-`*things*; one of them is `--force-confold`, or conversely `--force-confnew` to always replace any existing configuration file. (Many modern packages have a facility to upgrade any unchanged configurations completely automatically, but manually changed configuration files still require manual updating or merging.)

If you aren't running `dpkg` directly, `apt` and friends allow you to pass options to it with

```
apt install -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install package
```

(Yeah, that's a lot of colons. You probably want `install -y` to avoid interactive prompting by Apt itself, too.)

Setting the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` to the string `noninteractive` will make Debconf (the configuration management component of Debian) select the default answer for all questions, and disable any prompting.

If the default answers to a package's configuration questions are not suitable, you can *preseed* Debconf's configuration database with the settings you want. You'll need to install `debconf-utils` which contains the utility `debconf-set-selections`. See further [its man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/debconf-set-selections.1.html) and e.g. some sections of https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed (though this is rather focused on preseeding the installer, so you can potentially perform an unattended installation of all of Debian).

---

The problem with

```
yes | dpkg -i package.deb
```

is that you can't exactly predict which prompts are going to be shown, depending on the package's and the hosting system's configuration; you might say `yes` to something you didn't want to, or perhaps tell the system that your domain name or default database user is `yes`. Debconf was designed to give you very detailed and, for the most part, very safe and robust control over package installation - use that power.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with debian 10 image specifically for installing mssql client, I have solved this issue by setting:

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

RUN dpkg --install msodbcsql18_18.2.1.1-1_amd64.deb && 
dpkg --install mssql-tools18_18.2.1.1-1_amd64.deb